# how to add time stamp for each row in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I am trying to add **time** column in the target table and then add unique time for each record.

EX: time
    11:26:33
    11:26:34
    11:26:35
    11:26:36

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SYSTIMESTAMP() function to get a timestamp for each record:

```
Port Name       Port Type        Expression
-------------------------------------------
v_format        Variable         'NS'
o_timestamp     Output           SYSTIMESTAMP(v_format)
```

Note that you have to use the format string ('SS','MS','NS' or 'US') as a variable for Informatica to evaluate the function for each row. If you specify the format string as a constant like this `SYSTIMESTAMP('NS')`, Informatica evaluates the function once and retains its value for each row in the transformation.

Comment: of course I did that but in the target it is showing only single time like 11:24:33.9 (Even I used Nano seconds)

Comment: Modified the answer.

Comment: @Samik I implemented your solution of having a variable with 'NS' and then using it in the timestamp column. But it still gives the same timestamp for all records. I'm using Informatica BDM 10.2.2  Do you know of other way? Also, instead of using SYSTIMESTAMP, I would like to get the date/timestamp info from the filename and make it look unique for each record. Is this possible? If so, can you please suggest an approach? I highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.